# ElasticSearch: Return the query within the response body when hits = 0

Tags: elasticsearch

***Please note that the following example is a very minified version of a real life use case, it is for the question to be easy to read and to make a point.***

I have the following document structure:

```
{
   "date" : 1400500,
   "idc" : 1001,
   "name": "somebody",
}
```

I am performing an _msearch query (multiple searchs at a time) based on different values (the "idc" and a "date" range) 
When ES could not find any documents for the given date range it returns:

```
"hits":{  
    "total":0,
    "max_score":null,
    "hits":[  
    ]
}
```

But, since there are N results, I cannot tell which "idc" and what "date" range was this result for.
I would like the response to have the "searched" date range and "idc" when there are no results for the given query. 
for example, if I am searching documents for IDC = 1001 and date between 1400100 and 1400200, but there are no results found, the response should have the query terms in the response body, something like this:

```
"hits":{  
    "total":0,
    "max_score":null,
    "query": {
           "date": {
               "gt": 1400100,
               "lte": 1400200,
           }
           "idc": 1001,
       }
}
```

That way I can tell what date range and "idc" combination has no results.

 ***Please note that the above example is a very minified version of a real life use case, it is for the question to be easy to read and to make a point.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the docs

> multi search API(_msearch) response returns a responses array, which includes the search
>   response and status code for each search request **matching its order in
>   the original multi search request**.

since you know the order in which you sent the requests , you can find out which request failed.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html